# When to use Public or Private when declaring variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This may be a really basic question but I'm hoping for some clarification, and the reason for the post is because recently I've been told repeatedly and seen in other posts to never use `public` when declaring a variable so I'm a bit confused. This also includes `[SerializeField]`. I try to use `private` to declare variables whenever I can, but when I need to reference a variable from another script I need to change the variable from `private` to `public` otherwise I get the "variable is inaccessible due to protection level". Is that acceptable or is there a way around this?

Because currently I have around 30 variables in one large script of mine and 25 of the 30 are all `public`.

```
// ScriptA
public bool testBool;
private bool testBool;
[SerializeField] private bool testBool;
```

If I was to reference one of those three bools in another script (for example ScriptB), only the `public bool testBool` would work, and the same would apply if I used a `float`, `Vector3`, and so on instead of a `bool`.

And when using something like `[SerializeField] private bool testBool;` This also gives the same "inaccessible" error when trying to use that bool inside of a different script so I'm just curious if I should do anything or just leave it and continue with my approach.

Comment: The recommendation is to use private fields/properties by default. But if a field or property needs to be public it is fine to make it public. Types meant for serialization often need all fields and properties to be public, in some cases it can be useful to create separate types that are only used for serialization, often called "Data Transfer Objects (DTO)".

Comment: the key difference is private means only that class can mess with the value, public anything can, so it makes your own life easier if it is private where possible.. but somethings have to be public, you can have properties where its readable and not settable, or, readable and settable with a method, but, in the end if theres data in your class something else needs it has to be let out somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general you want to make all things as little accessible as possible (**Encapsulation**)!

So things should be in this order

- as `private` as possible (therefore it is also the default/implicit accessibility for type members)
- `protected` in case of inheritance requires it
- `internal` - meaning only accessible to everything within the same assembly (also default accessibility for types - people using `public` most commonly is a bad habit imho - in which I fall myself ;) )
- and finally `public` if it actually provides some global API and is required outside of the assembly

*For some very special and edgy cases - like e.g. Tests - you can also expose certain assembly bridges via [`[InternalsVisibleTo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=net-7.0)*

*There are also other cases were you would want to stick with having more things `public` like e.g. when it comes to modding - see comments below*

*And especially in Unity it is simply faster to type `public` in order to expose something to the Inspector so - for quick and rough prototyping - we often do this,but it should be fixed once the code is actually coming stable*

---

Also in general in c# it is kinda common practice to rather use [**properties**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for anything public (see e.g. [Is it bad practice to use public fields?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields))

In very short: They basically are getter/setter methods. These can either have a [backing field and implement additional logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields) or be [auto-properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#auto-implemented-properties) like the example below. Additionally you can control the `set`(ter) part's accessibility (in theory you *can* also for the `get` but it is quite unusual to have a `set` with a higher accessibility than a `get`)

Unity even undocumented supports the **auto-properties** to be serialized in the Inspector using

```
[field: SerializeField] public bool SomeBool { get; private set; }
```

... so no, public **fields** is not the *only* way to provide values to other scripts.

---

There are many many ways - so basically it comes down a bit to preferences and your use case.

In general I would go for

```
// This is only used by this type
private bool someBool;
```

if this is required to be adjusted by the user - aka Inspector

```
// This is only used by this type
[SerializeField] private bool someBool;
```

and if it is required to be **read** by another script you can either go

```
// That's the backing field approach
public bool SomeBool => someBool;

// equals
public bool SomeBool
{
    get => someBool;
}
// equals
public bool SomeBool
{
    get
    {
        return someBool;
    }
}
```

or as said use the serialized auto-property

```
[field: SerializeField] public bool SomeBool { get; private/*or protected*/set };
```

and only if other scripts also **set** this you can use a

```
// For simplicity and less typing effort
// I also use this for fast prototyping and quickly expose things in the Inspector
// but this shouldn't stay the long-term code
public bool SomeBool;
```

For runtime stuff you can simply stick to

```
// Can have a default value and behaves similar to a public field
public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
```

but you can also expose it in the Inspector if needed

```
[field: SerializeField] public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
```

Auto-properies can - like fields - also be directly initialized with a value.

---

*Sidenote*: The serialized property comes with a little hickup regarding custom `Editor` implementations - you have to go through the virtual backing field `serializedObject.FindProperty($"<{propertyName}>k__BackingField")`

Comment: Do you need to use `{ get; set; }` for every bool or is it case by case? I haven't run into any issue with just a generic `private bool testBool;` But this answers all the questions I had, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: @RelevantUni98 well the `{ get; set; }` as I said makes your bool not a **field** but rather a **property** .. I/You wouldn't use a property for something that is `private` ;)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will keep this open so I can completely understand everything you said

Comment: @derHugo: excellent reply.  Thank you for mentioning the significance of C# "properties".  One additional note: `Declaration` declares the creation of variables and functions. `Initialization` assigns initial values to variables. `Instantiating` an object means to create a new instance of the class.  `Access modifiers` like "private" are part of the "Declaration".

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks! I know the phrases - did I formulate anything in a misunderstanding/misleading way?

Comment: For games in particular, there's another subtle consideration for public vs internal.  Using public for cases where you need cross-class access makes the code slightly more accessible for modders.  Modders have ways around these access limitations, but unless you have several modules that really need the clear insulation boundaries, using internal doesn't really add much value.  The vast majority of Unity games I've modded have almost all their scripts in one assembly (with third-party components in other assemblies.)

Comment: @DanBryant well I rather come from industrial side and are more the dev of such third-party tools, packages, libraries ;) For those you would rather want them to only expose what is really required/supposed ;)  .. so as said `basically it comes down a bit to preferences and your use case.`

Comment: @derHugo, Agreed, when making third party libraries, it makes sense to minimize the public surface as much as possible, since you have multiple consumers and need to support them.

Answer (score 1):

If your script was an library you can use internal as well.
Internal types or members are accessible only within files in the same **assembly**.

If it's not a library, I'm sorry, you should explain yourself better.

```cs
public namespace baseNameSpace
{
    public class BaseClass
    {  
       internal static int intM = 0;  
    }  
}
public namespace testNameSpace
{
    public class TestAccess
    {  
       static void Main()
       {  
          var myBase = new baseNameSpace.BaseClass();   // Ok.  
          BaseClass.intM = 444;    // CS0117  
       }  
    }
}
```